# my.cnf file missing and cannot be found at any directory

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, centos6, my.cnf

I recently removed mysql 5.1 an installed mysql 5.6 on my CENTOS 6 x86 OS.
When I try to look for the my.cnf file it is missing from these directories:

`mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"`

=

`/etc/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, and `~/.my.cnf`.

Now I went to my mysql home directory which is /var/lib/mysql to find the .cnf file but all I found was auto.cnf.

Does anyone have any ideas? Could I just download a my.cnf file and place it in one of those directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sudo updatedb && locate my.cnf

Comment: What woud be the CENTOS OS way of doing it? :)

`yum updatedb && locate my.cnf`? I tried `locate my.cnf` but it says `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db no such file or dir`.

Comment: yum is to manage (install, remove) software, try to locate the file with root user

Answer (score 0):

if you are having trouble with locate

as root: find / -name my.cnf

how did you install mysql? with yum?

Comment: A `-type f` would speed things up dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Centos 6.5.  When I went to install MySQL-server.X86_64 5.6.12-2.el6, it put my.cnf in /usr.  /usr/my.cnf ?  What the hell is my.cnf doing in /usr ?

I found it using find / -iname my.cnf -print

Answer (score 0):

The location is changed to `/mysql.d`, and the filename is changed to something like `mysqld.cnf`. Also, there's a similar question somewhere (maybe duplicate here or there).

Answer (score 0):

on windows the my.ini is stored under:
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini